# how to get all matching records from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table set in my mysql database

```
mem_id | pid | content
     0 |   1 | All the content is here
     0 |   2 | All the content is here
     0 |   3 | All the content is here
```

Now the problem is to get all matching `mem_id` values and store it in a array in php.

Example: A variable called `$id` has value `0`

So now I have to get all values under the column content but only those which matches the `mem_id` of the user.

Could anyone help me with this, I need it in php and using mysql query to get all the values.

My current code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","*****","******","*****");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE mem_id = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]' LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $friends = $row['fid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTABLE WHERE mem_id=0   // or 1 or 2 or 3 etc
```

Using **PHP** you could query it like:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$id = intval($id);  // Put your ID here
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTABLE WHERE mem_id=$id";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     print_r($row); 
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="select * from TABLE_NAME where `mem_id`='$id'";
```